# How to flush machine underflows to zero and prevent conversion to arbitrary precision?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics

I'm working on some pretty intense computation in *Mathematica*; when my code started running slowly, I tracked the source of the problem to `Exp[]`. I need to exponentiate every element of a 50x500x500 array; performing the operation on a 500x500 array takes on the order of 3 seconds (according to `AbsoluteTime`), so the entire array should take about 50 times that. Unfortunately, that's calculation needs to happen for every data point.

I've read about lots of ways to speed up *Mathematica* code, but none of those methods seem to apply here. I'm already working in `MachinePrecision`. I have noticed that some of my results are ridiculously small (for example, `4.282835067271648*10^-78127094`), but I'm not sure how to make *Mathematica* ignore those; they're obviously **much** smaller than `$MachineEpsilon`.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

**Update**:

Below is a sample of my code and the generated output. To give it some context, `g0`, is a scalar, `σg0` is a length 50 array, and `g` is a 500x500 array.

```
(* Added after Oleksandr R.'s comment *)
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False];

n = Length[σg0];
probgs = ConstantArray[N[0], {50, 500, 500}];
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
  probgs[[i]] = 
    N[(1/(Sqrt[2 π] σg0[[i]])) Exp[-0.5 ((g - g0)/σg0[[i]])^2]];
  ]; // AbsoluteTiming
Precision[probgs]
```

Output:

```
{4.816275, Null}
MachinePrecision
```

Turning off underflow definitely helped; 5 seconds isn't bad at all for what I'm doing.

Comment: `xxx = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {50, 500, 500}]; Exp[xxx];` takes about 0.04 seconds for me.

Comment: Please supply the code you use. As per @b.gatessucks comment, `Exp` is most likely *not* the bottleneck.

Comment: `4.282835067271648*10^-78127094` is *not* a `MachinePrecision` number, so actually you are working in arbitrary precision. You have been caught out by automatic underflow handling, whereas clearly you would rather that such numbers go to (machine) zero. Evaluate `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]` and try again.

Comment: If you're evaluating `Exp[]` at very tiny arguments, you might consider replacing `Exp[]` with a suitably chosen Padé approximant.

Comment: When dealing with probabilities, sometimes it can be more efficient to work with their natural logarithm instead of the probabilities themselves.

Comment: What *is* `\[Sigma]g0`? Standalone means it should run from a fresh kernel w/o any alterations. The *actual* arrays matter and you cannot expect other users to bother to generate dummys.

Comment: @OleksandrR., could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? I don't want to leave this post hanging, and your idea solved my problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Obviously, for large negative inputs, `Exp` will produce very small numbers. While this isn't intrinsically problematic, it so happens that, by default, *Mathematica* deals with machine underflow by converting the affected values to an arbitrary precision representation in order to avoid catastrophic loss of precision. However, sometimes one would rather disregard underflowed values instead (i.e. let them go to zero), and indeed that seems to be the case here.

This behavior can be controlled using the system option `"CatchMachineUnderflow"`--simply use

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]
```

and underflowed values will be flushed to (machine precision) zero.

Since this is a global option that will most likely affect the results of system functions as well as user code, it's advisable to localize its effect as tightly as possible. For this purpose one can use the undocumented function `` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``, as described by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586910):

```
With[{cmuopt = SystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow"]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False],
  (* put your own code here; for example: *)
  Exp[-1000.],
  SetSystemOptions[cmuopt]
 ]
]
(* 0.` *)
```

Contrast this with:

```
Exp[-1000.]
(* 5.0759588975494567652918094795743369258164499728`12.954589770191006*^-435 *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, my Tarot-Cards are in repair so here is a guess:

```
data = yourSecertData;
Precisionp[data]
pd = Developer`ToPackedArray[N[data, $MachinePrecision]];
(* must be True *)
Developer`PackedArrayQ[pd]
AbsoluteTiming[pd];
cExp = Compile[{{in, _Real, 2}}, Exp[in], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, CompilationTarget -> "C"];
AbsoluteTiming[cExp[pd]]
```

You may also want to play with the "Listable" setting and the tensor rank (2) and see if parallel execution helps, or if compilation to "C" is needed. (Maybe "WVM" is enough). If using the compiler seems helpful, may want to look up other compiler options (`RuntimeOptions`).

Update:

After more info was available:

```
cf = With[{g0 = g0}, 
  Compile[{{og0, _Real, 0}, {g, _Real, 
     2}}, (1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] og0)) Exp[-0.5 ((g - g0)/og0)^2], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable]]
```

This should speed up things considerably.

Comment: Compiling can be just as esoteric as the tarot cards, though :-)

Comment: @YvesKlett, :-) lol.

Comment: @ruebenko, I tried messing around with `Compile` for a while, but it complained about a pure function I had defined and, in the end, crashed my system. I never figured out what I was doing wrong, unfortunately.

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars, it may actually be helpful if you post that code such that this can be verified/fixed/improved. None can answer you question without seeing the code. This is like saying my bike is slow, can fix it?

Comment: @ruebenko, I added the code just now. What I posted should run standalone.

Answer (score 2):

You will save some time by computing `-0.5 (g-g0)^2` just once:

```
probgs = With[{gg = -0.5 (g - g0)^2},
    Table[1/(Sqrt[2 Pi] sg0[[i]]) Exp[gg / sg0[[i]]^2], {i, n}]];
```