# Product of elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, language-design, arithmetic, function-comparison

`Sum` is for functions; `Total` is for a list. `Product` is for a function; what is the command for a list? I'd have guessed `Times`, but not so. Using tricks like `Times @@ <list>` I could make it work, but what is the command for product of elements of a list?

Comment: I'm curious, what is it you don't like about `Times @@ list`?

Comment: `Tr[{1, 2, 3, 4}, Times]` works too, but is not really better than using `Apply`.

Answer (score 22):

The usual way to multiply all elements of a list is `Times @@ list`.

---

The less trivial problem is to calculate the product as fast as possible. Some performance tests (from slowest to fastest):

```
SeedRandom[0];
a = RandomReal[{0.999, 1.001}, 10000000];

Det@DiagonalMatrix[a] // AbsoluteTiming
(* I don't have 1 PB RAM :) *)

Product[a[[i]], {i, Length[a]}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.516518, 0.323758} *)

1 ## & @@ a // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.724335, 0.323758} *)

Tr[a, Times] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.140270, 0.323758} *)

Times @@ a // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.742130, 0.323758} *)

Fold[Times, 1., a] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.592785, 0.323758} *)

Times @@ Times @@ Partition[a, 2000] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.249095, 0.323758} *)

Exp@Total@Log@a // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.185068, 0.323758} *)

cTimes = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Module[{res = 1.}, Do[res *= x[[i]], {i, Length[x]}];
   res], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
cTimes[a] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.032927, 0.323758} *)
```

`Exp@*Total@*Log` have a big advantage: it doesn't go to underflow or overflow if you work with a wide range of numbers (numbers should be positive, see Steve's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99512/4678)).

---

One can go further and allow compiler to use vector instructions

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
srcTimes = "#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
  DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){return WolframLibraryVersion;}
  DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData){return 0;}
  DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize(WolframLibraryData libData){return;}
  DLLEXPORT int times(WolframLibraryData libData,
            mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    double r = 1.0;
    double *data;
    MTensor T0 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    mint len = libData->MTensor_getFlattenedLength(T0);
    data = libData->MTensor_getRealData(T0);
    mint i;
    for(i = 0; i < len-1; i+=2){
        r *= data[i]*data[i+1];
    }
    for(; i < len; i++){
        r *= data[i];    
    }
    MArgument_setReal(Res, r);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }";
libTimes = CreateLibrary[srcTimes, "times"];
cTimes2 = LibraryFunctionLoad[libTimes, "times", {{_Real, 1, "Constant"}}, _Real];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
cTimes[a] // AccurateTiming
cTimes2[a] // AccurateTiming
(* 0.0279596 *)
(* 0.0171085 *)
```

Comment: I see that you chose to interpret the question as equivalent to my own from Stack Overflow: [Is there a fast product operation for PackedArrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5294640/) +1 :-)

Comment: p.s. belisarius's comment still cracks me up: **"Ohh well, my sense of humor is asymptotically approaching idiocy as years go by. –  belisarius"**

Comment: I always use Exp@Total@Log@a, glad to see it performs well since that is the one that makes the most sense to me.

Comment: I think this timing test may be deceptive. If you change the character of the input to `a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10000000];` then the order of timings is completely scrambled.

Comment: @bills It is because you obtain overflow and non-numeric values.

Comment: @ybeltukov -- you still get  scrambled timings (without underflow) if you only multiply a million items (instead of 10 million).

Comment: @bills I have the same order of timings for `RandomReal[{0.95, 1.05}, 1000000]`. For bigger variance I obtain underflow.

Comment: What I just ran was: `a = RandomReal[{-2.5, 2.5}, 1000000];` You do get small numbers 10^-36112, but no underflow.

Comment: @bills Actually it *is* machine underflow. It is mush less then `$MinMachineNumber`. You can set [`SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24857/4678) to obtain desired timings (with rounded to 0.0 result).

Answer (score 12):

Ah well, for fun and posterity:

`Tr[#, Times]`&

Answer (score 8):

At present I don't believe there is a core language function for this operation.  `Times @@ list` is standard practice from what I have observed.  Just for fun you could also use:

```
1 ## & @@ {a, b, c, d}
```

> ```
> a b c d
> ```

---

I was remiss not to link my own question on the subject with a nice answer from [Simon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34/simon):

- [Is there a fast product operation for PackedArrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5294640/)

Be aware that there is a trade-off of precision for speed with the `Log` method.

Comment: That´s what you get for asking a perfectly innocent question around here :D

Answer (score 8):

#### Why is there no equivalent of `Total` for products?

There isn't an equivalent of `Total` for products, and I believe that there is a reason.

The high performance of `Total` (compared to `Plus`) becomes especially important for large arrays.  Adding together lots of numbers is usually straightforward.  But multiplying them has a high risk of over- or underflow.

Example:

```
Times @@ RandomReal[1, 10000]
(* 3.49264640062689*10^-4292 *)

Times @@ RandomReal[10, 10000]
(* 1.26694123858894*10^5708 *)
```

These results are well under and over the smallest and largest representable machine numbers:

```
{$MinMachineNumber, $MaxMachineNumber}
(* {2.22507*10^-308, 1.79769*10^308} *)
```

Mathematica *can* deal with such huge and tiny numbers, but it must use arbitrary precision arithmetic, which is slow anyway.

We must keep this in mind in the experiments we will do below.

#### What are fast ways to multiply numbers in a list?

To minimize the risk of under/overflow, let us use the following array for benchmarking:

```
arr = RandomReal[E, 100000];
```

The simplest way is `Times @@ arr`, but this is not particularly fast.  [The reason is unpacking.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145045/12)

```
Times @@ arr // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.014, 2.55876*10^191} *)
```

Several of the tricks shown in this thread, like `Tr[arr, Times]`, are basically the same thing.

The simplest fast way is

```
Product[a, {a, arr}] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0014, 2.55876*10^191} *)
```

I generally recommend this approach.

The fastest way, at the cost of accuracy, is transforming the product to a sum using logarithms:

```
Exp@Total@Log[arr] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.000106, 2.55876*10^191} *)
```

This approach makes sense given the nature of the operation: the results will typically span orders of magnitude.  The under/overflow is delayed until the final `Exp`.  The thing to watch out for is precision and the presence of negative values.

What about compilation?

Direct procedural approaches with `Compile` are going to be equivalent to (and perform similarly with)

```
cf = Compile[{{arr, _Real, 1}},
  Product[a, {a, arr}]
]
```

Benchmarking shows that this is no better than a naked `Product`.  Perhaps `Product` already auto-compiled?

```
cf[arr] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0014, 2.55876*10^191} *)
```

It does becomes faster if we compile to C:

```
cf = Compile[{{arr, _Real, 1}},
  Product[a, {a, arr}],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
]

cf[arr] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00014, 2.55876*10^191} *)
```

The important thing to pay attention to here is under- and overflow.  Because compiled functions operate with machine numbers, under- or overflow will not only affect performance.  It will also affect the result.

Observe:

```
arr = RandomReal[2, 100000];

cf[arr]
(* 0. *)
```

The result is not really zero.  The function returns zero only because of underflow.  The true result is

```
Product[a, {a, arr}] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.023, 1.87228152952573*10^-13556} *)
```

Notice that after underflow, `Product` becomes much slower, even slower than `Times @@ ...`.  This is due to having to switch to arbitrary precision arithmetic.  But it does give us the correct result.

The fix is to explicitly instruct `Compile` to handle under/overflows:

```
cf = Compile[{{arr, _Real, 1}},
  Product[a, {a, arr}],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> {"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> True, "CatchMachineOverflow" -> True}
]

cf[arr] // RepeatedTiming

During evaluation of CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

During evaluation of CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
(* {0.024, 1.87228152952573*10^-13556} *)
```

Now for *this array*, the compiled function is not any faster than the plain `Product`, because it must resort to uncompiled evaluation anyway.  But it does return the correct result, and the compiled function still has the potential to be fast for other arrays.  Unfortunately, under- and overflow checking in `Compile` does seem to introduce a performance penalty.

---

#### To sum up

1. The fastest way is always transforming to a sum: `Exp@Total@Log[arr]`. This may deteriorate accuracy and will not work for negative numbers.
2. The fastest *direct* way is `Product[a, {a, arr}]`.
3. If you compile solution (2), expect a speedup only with `CompilationTarget -> "C"`, and remember to turn on catching under- and overflows using `RuntimeOptions -> {"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> True, "CatchMachineOverflow" -> True}`.

Comment: I had a look to see if `GeometricMean` did anything clever and found ``Statistics`DescriptiveDump`ApplyToPacked`` which effectively switches on autocompile for `Apply` so that it works without unpacking. For this problem it's no better than using `Product` but I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: This is not quite true: Exp@Total@Log works also for negatives! Exp and Log do the job brilliantly together so that the final result is real again.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Exp Total Log form should be avoided in general, esp. if some values are negative due to accuracy issues. Consider the nasty value from the above example with the sign flipped shown below. Since 10 million is an even number, the product should be the same.

```
a = RandomReal[{0.999, 1.001}, 10000000];

AbsoluteTiming[Times @@ a]
(* {1.4060804, 0.243018} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Exp@Total@Log@a]
(* {0.1490085, 0.243018} *)

Log[-3]
(* I π + Log[3] *)

AbsoluteTiming[Exp@Total@Log@(-a)]
(* {0.7520430, 0.243011 + 0.00184219 I} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Tr[a, Times]]
(* {1.4640838, 0.243018} *)

AbsoluteTiming[Times @@ (-a)]
(* {1.2720727, 0.243018} *)
```

Comment: +1 You are right. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5308395/2379045) is a workaround for Exp-Total-Log method.

Comment: No, there is no problem with negatives at all! The "I pi" which comes from the log(-x) is again converted to -1 by Exp!

Answer (score 2):

```
Det[DiagonalMatrix[#]] &
```

:P

Answer (score 2):

This is not terse but just wanted to play:

```
Fold[#1 #2 &, #, ##2] &@{a, b, c, d}
```

yields:

> `a b c d`

Comment: As ybeltukov shows  I am unnecessarily complex: Fold[Times,1,#]&

Answer (score 1):

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} /. List -> Times
```

Comment: One could expect here: `{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}` the result `{1,4}` not `4`.

Comment: how about Flatten -:)