# Multiply elements within a list

Tags: list-manipulation

How do I multiply elements within a list?

```
list = {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7}, {8,9}}
```

Desired output:

```
{1, 6, 120, 7, 72}
```

Comment: try Times @@@ list

Comment: Now, which of [these](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1352) [two](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62984) is the dupe?

Comment: @J.M. , it's almost as if the other question should just be edited to have the text of this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most Efficient Way to Calculate the Product of All Items in a List?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/most-efficient-way-to-calculate-the-product-of-all-items-in-a-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

or type:

```
Apply[Times, list, {1}]
```

This is less elegant than the shorthand `Times @@@ list` but shows how Times can be applied to different levelspecs.