# The command Total sums the entries of a list, is there a comparable command for the product of entries of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, language-design, products

I recently just found out about the command Total that gives the sum of a list. Was wondering whether there's an analogue that gives the product of the entries of a list? I see that there is the command Times, but that doesn't accept lists as input.

If one performs Total on a list, I imagine that the computation is as fast as using Sum. Might it be speedier (probably more an academic question, than a practically meaningful one)?

The stack exchange pointed me to this posting [listProduct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/most-efficient-way-to-calculate-the-product-of-all-items-in-a-list)--which seems highly relevant, if not definitive in this matter.

Also, [whynocounterpartfunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171641/why-it-seems-that-there-is-no-counterpart-function-as-to-multiplication-to-tot/171643#171643)

So, it seems that this issue is not original to me.

So, should I simply define a listProduct function, and let that settle the matter (and move onto more substantive issues)?

P. S. Also, [ProductElements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62984/product-of-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: Rather than using your list as an input, you can Apply the head Times to the inputs: Times@@yourlist

Comment: Regarding speed, in my own experience `Total` is usually faster than `Sum` if you already have the list constructed. `Apply[Times, ...]` (`Times@@...`) should be quite fast as well. Use `Sum` and `Product` if you are not constructing the list in full first.

Comment: Asked and answered in the question you linked yourself: [Most Efficient Way to Calculate the Product of All Items in a List?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1352/27951) (the answer is `Times@@list`, as mentioned). I recommend closing as duplicate. I also recommend against defining a `listProduct` when `Times@@list` is compact and obvious in its purpose.

Comment: For flat lists (i.e., vectors), you can also use `Tr[list, Times]`. For example: `Tr[Range[5], Times]`