# Calculating eigensystem of a matrix containing very small numbers

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I'm dealing with a matrix containing very small numbers like 10^(-370). When I compute the eigensystem of my matrix, it takes too much time, though the matrix size is not large.

Can anyone explain why this happens and what I can do to improve performance?

Comment: If you would  share your code attempts (hopefully is a well [formatted way](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)), we may quickly see the problem you are facing.

Comment: These numbers are smaller then minimum possible machine numbers and the corresponding problem is called "machine underflow". `N` can't helps here. I believe that `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]` will solve your problem. The closely related question is [How to flush machine underflows to zero and prevent conversion to arbitrary precision?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24857/4678).

Comment: Thank you so much ybeltukov. You have saved me. Thanks a bunch.