# Why does DSolve return two solutions for my ODE?

Tags: differential-equations

I wanted to solve the differential equation: $y’ = (1+2x)\sqrt{y}$ with $y(0) = 1$. It can be done by hand, and to check my answer I typed the following in *Mathematica*

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == (1 + 2 x)Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y[x] ,x]// FullSimplify
```

Surprisingly *Mathematica* gave me two solutions:

> ```
> {{y[x] -> 1/4 (-2 + x + x^2)^2}, {y[x] -> 1/4 (2 + x + x^2)^2}}
> ```

The second solution is what I got by hand. However, I don’t see how *Mathematica* got the first solution.

If I use it, I get y’(0) = -1, but according to the differential equation $y’(0)= (1+2*0)\sqrt{y(0)} = 1$.

I can see that it is a solution of $y'(x)^2 = ((1+2x)\sqrt{y})^2$, but that ODE is not equivalent to $y’ = (1+2x)\sqrt{y}$.

And when I run the following *Mathematica* code:

```
s1[x_] = 1/4 (-2 + x + x^2)^2; 
s2[x_] = 1/4 (2 + x + x^2)^2;
check1[x_] = s1'[x] - (1 + 2 x) Sqrt[s1[x]];
check2[x_] = s2'[x] - (1 + 2 x) Sqrt[s2[x]];
Plot[{check1[x]}, {x, -3, 1.5}]
Plot[{check2[x]}, {x, -3, 1.5}]
```

I can see that `check2[x]` is identically zero, but not `check1[x]`.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi ! Please, go to the help centre, read a bit about code formatting and improve your post.

Comment: Looks to me like the first solution does satisfy the initial condition `y[0]==1` but satisfies the differential equation only when `x <= -2 || x >= 1`. [that's the condition that allows simplifying `\Sqrt[(-2 + x + x^2)^2)` to `-2 + x + x^2`.]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: added handling special case of x == -1/2

Expanding on comment by@murray

```
eqns = {y'[x] == (1 + 2 x) Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 1};

sol = DSolve[eqns, y, x]
```

> {{y -> Function[{x}, 
>            (1/4)*(4 - 4*x - 3*x^2 + 
>                 2*x^3 + x^4)]},     {y -> Function[{x}, 
>            (1/4)*(4 + 4*x + 5*x^2 + 
>                 2*x^3 + x^4)]}}

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify
```

> {{(1 + 2*x)*(-2 + x + x^2 - 
>               Sqrt[(-2 + x + x^2)^2]) == 0, 
>        True},     {(1 + 2*x)*(2 + x + x^2 - 
>               Sqrt[(2 + x + x^2)^2]) == 0, 
>        True}}

The second solution is valid for

```
Reduce[2 + x + x^2 >= 0 || x == -1/2, x]
```

> Element[x, Reals] || x == -(1/2)

However, Element[x, Reals] encompasses the special case of x == -1/2

```
eqns /. sol[[2]] // Simplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &
```

> {True, True}

The first solution requires that

```
Reduce[-2 + x + x^2 >= 0 || x == -1/2, x]
```

> x <= -2 || x >= 1 || x == -(1/2)

So the second solution is valid for all real x and both solutions are valid for x <= -2 or x > 1 or x == -1/2

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify[#, x < -2 || x >= 1 || x == -1/2] &
```

> {{True, True}, {True, True}}

Answer (score 3):

#### First: Getting the right solution

Using [`` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/how-to-flush-machine-underflows-to-zero-and-prevent-conversion-to-arbitrary-prec/25668#25668) to set the `Method -> Reduce` option on `Solve`, and adding the assumption `x ∈ Reals`, we get the correct answer:

```
sys = {y'[x] == (1 + 2 x) Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 1};

With[{opts = Options[Solve]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce],
  s = Assuming[x ∈ Reals,
    y -> Function @@ {x, y[x] /. #} & /@    (* turn the expression into a Function *)
     Simplify@DSolve[sys, y[x], x]          (* Simplify the solution *)
    ],
  SetOptions[Solve, opts]
  ]]
sys /. s // Simplify[#, x ∈ Reals] &

> Solve::useq: The answer found by Solve contains equational condition(s) {0==1/2 (x+x^2+Reduce`ReduceVar[2]-Sqrt[Plus[<<3>>]^2])}. A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions. >>

(*
  {y -> Function[x, 1/4 (2 + x + x^2)^2]}
  {True, True}
*)
```

Without the assumption `x ∈ Reals` , we also get the right answer but in a less convenient form, with an unsimplified `ConditionalExpression` alluded to in the warning message:

```
{y -> Function[x, 
   ConditionalExpression[1/4 (2 + x + x^2)^2, Sqrt[(2 + x + x^2)^2] == 2 + x + x^2]]}
```

*Note:* I prefer the `Function` form of the solution `s` because the derivative(s) in a differential equation `sys` are automatically computed in `sys /. s`.  This seems convenient to me.

#### Second: What `DSolve` is doing

I think `DSolve` is doing what one normally does.  It solves for the general solution and then solves the initial condition for the constant of integration.  The problem is that it carries the general solution a little too far, which [Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346/chip-hurst) remarked on.

```
s = DSolve[{y'[x] == (1 + 2 x) Sqrt[y[x]]}, y, x]
(*  {{y -> Function[{x}, 1/4 (x^2 + 2 x^3 + x^4 + 2 x C[1] + 2 x^2 C[1] + C[1]^2)]}}  *)

Solve[y[0] == 1 /. s, C[1]]
(*  {{C[1] -> -2}, {C[1] -> 2}}  *)
```

Note the `C[1]^2` in `s`.  One problem at this stage is that one cannot determine which value of `C[1]` is correct *from the initial condition alone.*  You have to go back and check the ODE.  So `Method -> Reduce` is ineffective at this step:

```
Solve[y[0] == 1 /. s, C[1], Method -> Reduce]
(*  {{C[1] -> -2}, {C[1] -> 2}}  *)
```

Apparently `DSolve` does not go back and check.  I suppose there are reasons for this "laziness." It might take an unknown and long time to verify a potentially complicated solution, for instance.  But that could be handled with [`TimeConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstrained.html) and a warning message on time-out.

One can implement this strategy oneself, with or without `TimeConstrained`, as follows:

```
s = DSolve[{y'[x] == (1 + 2 x) Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, x];
Pick[s, TrueQ /@ And @@@ Simplify[sys /. s, x ∈ Reals]]
(* {{y -> Function[{x}, 1/4 (4 + 4 x + 5 x^2 + 2 x^3 + x^4)]}}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

If we run `WolframAlpha["y'[x] == (1 + 2 x)Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 1"]`, we can see the step by step solution, which exposes the issue at hand.

```
WolframAlpha["y'[x] == (1 + 2 x)Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 1"]
(* click the Step-by-step solution *)
```

[image]

Now, I cut off the image here on purpose.

Notice to solve for `y[x]`, we had to square both sides. This could give extraneous solutions, dependent on `x`, so `Solve` just gives the generic solution. This seems acceptable IMHO since `Solve` tries to return a list of rules. `Reduce` on the other hand does a better job:

```
Reduce[2 Sqrt[y[x]] == x^2 + x + C[1], y[x]]

During evaluation of In[58]:= Reduce::useq: The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s) {0==1/2 (x+x^2+C[1]-Sqrt[Plus[<<3>>]^2])}. A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions. >>
```

> ```
> 0 == 1/2 (x + x^2 + C[1] - Sqrt[(x + x^2 + C[1])^2]) && 
>  y[x] == 1/4 (x + x^2 + C[1])^2
> ```

[Here's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/accessing-reduce-from-dsolve) a post asking how to force `DSolve` to use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`. I'm not sure how well the solution works...

If you want to see a simpler example of why `Sqrt's` can give extraneous solutions, consider this example:

```
WolframAlpha["Sqrt[x] == -1"]
(* click the Step-by-step solution *)
```

[image]