# Result interpretation of a general solution of a nonlinear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

My goal is to find the general solution of the following nonlinear differential equation:

$$x'(t) = e^{-t} - \sqrt{x(t)}$$

Following [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroduction.html) guide, I've entered in the Wolfram Mathematica the following input:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == e^(-t) - sqrt(x[t])}, x[t], t]
```

and it printed me out this

```
{{x[t]->\[ExponentialE]^(-sqrt t) C[1]+e^(-t)/(sqrt-Log[e])}}
```

that I've interpreted as $$x(t) = c_1e^{-\sqrt{x}} + \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{\log{e}}}$$

I've tried to calculate the derivative of the output `x[t]` but it seems different from the initial one. In particular, I don't get why I got $\sqrt{-\log{e}} = i$ as denominator.

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT**

I fixed the input code in

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == \[ExponentialE]^(-t)-Sqrt[x[t]]},x[t],t]
```

and I got the following warning

> Solve::ifun :  Inverse functions are being used by  Solve , so some
>   solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution
>   information.

Actually, I don't know how to translate my `DSolve` command in a `Reduce` command.

Comment: Your `DSolve` contains many things that are just symbols without meaning to _Mathematica_. Try evaluating `sqrt(2)` for instance. Also `e` is not the natural base. All MMA built-ins are capitalized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to fix it ;)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I changed my code as explained in the EDIT section.

Comment: The equivalent commands `DSolve[(x'[u] + u^2)^2 == x[u] u^2, x, u]`, `DSolve[2 y[u] y'[u] == u (y[u] - u), y, u]` (`u == Exp[-t]`, `y[u] == Sqrt[x[u]]`) return unevaluated.  *Sometimes*, the warning indicates `DSolve` is almost there.  See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86739/4999) or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/4999) for getting `Solve` to use `Reduce` inside `DSolve`.  (BTW, it returns unevaluated, too, for your ODE.)

Comment: I probably should have added that when a command returns in the same form as it was called ("unevaluated"), it means that *Mathematica* cannot figure out the answer.  Sometimes reformulating the problem can lead to success, but not in the two ways I thought to try.

Comment: This is a Chini, see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveChiniEquations.html

Answer (score 2):

I use a substitution to solve:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Remove["Global`*"]

ode = x'[t] + Sqrt[x[t]] - Exp[-t];
```

first substitution is: `t = -Log[-s]`

```
T = -Log[-s];
ode2 = Expand[(ode /. {x[t] -> x[s], x'[t] -> x'[s]/D[T, s], t -> T})/s]
```

next substitution: `x[s] = v[s]^2/4`

```
XX[s_] := v[s]^2/4;
ode3 = Expand@Simplify[(ode2 /. x -> XX)*2, {v[s] \[Element] Reals, v[s] > 0}]
```

next substitution: `s = -Exp[m]`

```
SS = -Exp[m];
ode4 = Expand[(ode3 /. {v[s] -> v[m], v'[s] -> v'[m]/D[SS, m], s -> SS}) Exp[m]]
```

Then  I have a [Abel equation Second Kind in canonical form](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0126.pdf)

> $v(m) v'(m)-v(m)=-2 e^m \tag{1}$

**Bonus:** I'm convert `Abel equation Second Kind` to `Abel equation First Kind`

```
VV[m_] := -1/k[m];
ode5 = Expand[(ode4 /. v -> VV)*k[m]^3]
MM = Log[n];
ode6 = Expand[(ode5 /. {k[m] -> k[n], k'[m] -> k'[n]/D[MM, n], m -> MM})/n]
```

> $k'(n)=2 k(n)^3+\frac{k(n)^2}{n} \tag{2}$

I use's [this](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf) method to solve differential equation **`(1)`**

```
   Q[m_] := -2*Exp[m];
   Psi = FullSimplify[Sign[m]*Abs[m]*SinIntegral[m]];
   c = FullSimplify[(1/(-2*Psi^3))(1/2*Psi*Sin[2*m] - (2 + 1/(Sign[m]*Abs[m]))*Psi*Sin[m]^2 + 2*Psi^2*(Cos[m] - Sin[m]/(Sign[m]*Abs[m])) - Sin[m]^3)];
   a = -4;
   b = 3 - c - (4*Q[m])/(m + C[1]);
   p = -a^2/3 + b;
   q = 2*(a/3)^3 - a*b + c;
   BETA = 0.3218(* BETA = -0.12*Log[n]+0.3218, for n=1 *);

   SolveSol = Z /. Solve[Z^3 + p*Z + q == 0, Z][[1]](*Only a Real root*);
   sol = v[m] == 1/2*(m + C[1])*(BETA*SolveSol + 1/3);
```

Back all substitution:

```
   Solution = sol /. v[m] -> v /. m -> Log[-s] /. v -> Sqrt[4*x] /. s -> -Exp[-t] /. x -> x[t]
```

Then I have a huge long solution in implicit form.

Another we can solve in explicit form ,but MMA need some time to solve.

```
 Solution1 = 
 sol /. v[m] -> v /. m -> Log[-s] /. v -> Sqrt[4*x] /. s -> -Exp[-t]
 Solve[Solution1, x] /. x -> x[t]
```