# DSolve Returns Multiple Solutions to a Well-Posed Initial Value problem

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

The initial value problem: $dy/dx=x\sqrt{y},\;y(0)=1$ has the unique solution$$y=\frac 1{16}(x^4+8x^2+16)$$Mathematica's DSolve returns two solutions; the above and$$y=\frac 1{16}(x^4-8x^2+16)$$This second "solution" is erroneous.

Comment: Next time, please include explicit *Mathematica* code: `DSolve[{y'[x] == x Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, x]`. I believe this is a known long-standing bug in `DSolve[]` (but I'll let someone else add the [tag:bugs] tag). [Here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Mar/msg00308.html) is a more striking example.

Comment: Nearly the same: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86665/why-does-dsolve-return-two-solutions-for-my-ode

Answer (score 5):

```
eqns = {y'[x] == x Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 1};

sol = DSolve[eqns, y, x]

(*  {{y -> Function[{x}, 1/16 (16 - 8 x^2 + x^4)]}, {y -> 
   Function[{x}, 1/16 (16 + 8 x^2 + x^4)]}}  *)
```

The second solution is valid for all real x

```
eqns /. sol // FullSimplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &

(*  {{x^3 == x (4 + Abs[-4 + x^2]), True}, {True, True}}  *)

Reduce[x^3 == x (4 + Abs[-4 + x^2]), x, Reals]

(*  x <= -2 || x == 0 || x >= 2  *)
```

The first solutions is valid on the domain `x <= -2 || x == 0 || x >= 2`

```
eqns /. sol // FullSimplify[#, x <= -2 || x == 0 || x >= 2] &

(*  {{True, True}, {True, True}}  *)
```