# NDSolve DAE with Constraints

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I'm trying to make some numerical simulation with `NDSolve`. I have encountered a few problems. Here is a simplified version of the equations:

```
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
eq= {Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau], 
     Q[tau] - 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 == 0, 
     tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)] == 0, 
     vF[tau] - Clip[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])), {10^(-10), 100}] == 0,
     tt[1] == 15, tr[1] == 15, vF[1] == 100, Q[1] == 0}
```

Using `Clip` is to limit the vF in a specific range, e.g. between 0 and 100. 10^-10 is to prevent 1/0 error. I don't know if `WhenEvent` could do the same thing. The tae is an interpolated function. E.g.:

```
li = Import[http://web.archive.org/web/20180623011154/https://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/725958TYA.CSV];
tae = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[8760], Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}]]
```

But `NDSolve` complains about complex values if I try to solve the equations

```
sol0 = Flatten[NDSolveValue[eq, tt, {tau, 1, 24 365}]]
NDSolveValue::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

However, if I eliminate some equations with `Rule`, it runs smoothly.

```
rs = {Q -> 100 (28 - tr) vF 7/6,
   tr -> tt[tau] + (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF 0.22)],
   vF -> Clip[20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau]), {10^(-10), 100}]};
eq = Q - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau];
sol2 = Flatten[NDSolve[{eq //. rs, tt[1] == 15}, tt, {tau, 1, 24 365}]]
```

But why?

The real problem is much bigger and it's not very easy to eliminate some equations. Is there any other solution for this problem?

**EDIT**

Here are part of the data from the file.

```
li = {{0, 1.5}, {1, -1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {6, 10}, 
{7, 12}, {8, 14}, {9, 16}, {10, 17}, {11, 18}, {12, 20}, {13, 23}, 
{14, 23}, {15, 21}, {16, 17}, {17, 14}, {18, 12}, {19, 10}, 
{20, 9}, {21, 8}, {22, 4}, {23, 4}, {24, 1.5}};
tae = Interpolation[li];
sol0 = Flatten[NDSolveValue[eq, tt, {tau, 0, 24}]]
NDSolveValue::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended.
NDSolveValue::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

I think the `Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)]` is the problem. When `vF` drops to `10^-10`, this `Exp[]` become  extremely small near zero and `NDSolve` has difficulty to process it. Is there any way to avoid this?

**EDIT2**

@xzczd discovered that `Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)]` is not the root of this error message after trying [deactivating CatchMachineUnderflow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/how-to-flush-machine-underflows-to-zero-and-prevent-conversion-to-arbitrary-prec/25668#25668). It appears that NDSolve cannot process the `10^-10` in the `eq`. Increasing the `10^-10` to `0.1` solves the problem, but doesn't give me the accuracy I want. Any other solutions?

P.S. my intention is to prevent the `vF` becoming negative, so if there is any way to make `Clip[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])), {0, 100}]` working is also acceptable.

**EDIT3**

Here are the optimized initial conditions.

```
eq = {Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau], 
      Q[tau] - 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 == 0, 
      tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)] == 0,       
      vF[tau] - Clip[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])), {10^(-10), 100}] == 0}
ic = FindRoot[eq[[All, 1]] == 0 /. tau -> 0, 
   Transpose[{{Q[0], tt[0], tr[0], vF[0]}, {3000, 20, 20, 20}}]] /. 
  Rule -> Equal
sol = NDSolve[Join[eq, ic], {Q, tt, tr, vF}, {tau, 0, 24}]
NDSolve::mconly: For the method NDSolve`IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

Comment: Avoid DAE systems, if at all possible.

Comment: You might want to look into the [Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html). There are lots of tweeks to the `Methods` that may work in your case.

Comment: I suggest embedding the data for `li` into your post instead of giving it as an external link, that'll make your post more attractive. I know the original file is too large to post here, but I guess it's enough to reproduce the issue with just a small part of the data? (Actually I have difficulty in downloading the file here… )

Comment: @xzczd thanks for your advice. I added some data into this post.

Comment: I guess `eq` also needs modification for your new data? BTW, "When `vF` drops to `10^-10`, this `Exp[]` become extremely small near zero and `NDSolve` has difficulty to process it. " If this guess is correct, the technique here should work: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25668/1871

Comment: @xzczd `eq` should be the same. Are you able to generate the same error message?

Comment: OK, I managed to reproduce the error at `12.5369`, and the technique mentioned in my last comment doesn't work, so the root of the failure seems not to be that simple.

Comment: @xzczd the recommended technique also doesn't work for me.

Comment: @407Peezy, Mathematica also complains that your initial conditions are inconsistent, which they are. Mathematica is currently ignoring most of them and making things up.

Comment: @KraZug I've changed the initial conditions and they became consistent.

Comment: The data link is broken, do you have a backup?

Comment: @xzczd sadly I don't. But I will find something similar and put it in this post

Comment: Then this is a story telling us to avoid external link in question. Anyway I manage to find a backup, link fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the equations you have given in Case 3, putting a second `Clip` around the exponential is sufficient to keep the code to machine precision:

```
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
li = {{0, 1.5}, {1, -1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {6, 10}, {7, 12}, {8, 14}, 
     {9, 16}, {10, 17}, {11, 18}, {12, 20}, {13, 23}, {14, 23}, {15, 21}, {16, 17}, 
      {17, 14}, {18, 12}, {19, 10}, {20, 9}, {21, 8}, {22, 4}, {23, 4}, {24, 1.5}};
tae = Interpolation[li];
eq = {Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau], 
  Q[tau] - 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 == 0, 
  tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Clip[Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)], {10^-10, 100}] == 0, 
  vF[tau] - Clip[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])), {10^(-10), 100}] == 0}
ic = FindRoot[eq[[All, 1]] == 0 /. tau -> 0, 
      Transpose[{{Q[0], tt[0], tr[0], vF[0]}, {3000, 20, 20, 20}}]] /. Rule -> Equal
sol = NDSolve[Join[eq, ic], {Q, tt, tr, vF}, {tau, 0, 24}]
```

Using the full data, the solver thinks the system is singular at some point around `t=2124`, with `NDSolve::ndsz` (step size is effectively zero):

```
li = Import["http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/725958TYA.CSV"];
tae = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[8760], Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}]];
ic = FindRoot[eq[[All, 1]] == 0 /. tau -> 1,  Transpose[{{Q[1], tt[1], tr[1], vF[1]}, {3000, 20, 20, 20}}]] /. Rule -> Equal;
solfull0 = NDSolve[Join[eq, ic], {Q, tt, tr, vF}, {tau, 1, 8760}, MaxSteps -> ∞]
```

If we use the [`StateSpace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateSpace.html)
method, the solution can be found (in 90 seconds for me):

```
solfull = NDSolve[Join[eq, ic], {Q, tt, tr, vF}, {tau, 1, 8760}, 
   Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"StateSpace"}}, MaxSteps -> ∞]

Plot[tt[tau] /. solfull, {tau, 1, 8760}, AxesLabel -> {tau, "tt"}, PlotRange -> All, 
         LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium],  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

This looks the same as that given in bbgodfrey's post where the equations are transformed into a single ODE.

Comment: Although when I try the same for the full interpolation function posted, it gets to somewhere around `2130` before failing with `NDSolve::ndsz` - singularity or stiff system suspected, but I can't see any reason why this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It's a pity that this trick only works with part of the data, not the full interpolated function. I've struggle with this problem for months.

Comment: There is a weak singularity because of the clipping there.  Seems to trick `NDSolve` (or IDA) into thinking it's stiff.  I suppose it doesn't happen with the OP's 2nd, non-DAE system because LSODA is more robust.  But my *M* just crashed, and I hadn't saved my work on this problem. :/ Not that I felt I was close to solving it, so maybe not a big deal.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `NDSolve` has no difficulty to solve non-DAE version. But in the real problem, it is really painful to eliminate all the non-differential equations (maybe even impossible) because the system is so big. Is there any way to make IDA think it is not a stiff?

Comment: @407Peezy Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: @407Peezy, found a Method option that avoids the singular warning.

Comment: @KraZug …How much RAM is needed for `StateSpace` in this case?

Comment: @xzczd, `MaxMemoryUsed` gives me 50Mb.

Comment: There is a line in the StateSpace documentation that says "the method is implemented to allow arbitrary-precision solutions", and includes an example with working precision of 32. If I remove the second Clip it manages to get to $t=3568$ before throwing a convergence test error rather than the machine precision error of IDA.

Comment: Interesting. Just a side note: if you're not in _v11.3_, you need to execute `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]` first, or you'll run out of memory. (In _v11.3_ has changed the way machine number underflows are handled: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170462/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174474/1871)

Comment: Huh, I didn't think I had in that session (and still haven't updated to 11.3) I'll have to check myself in a bit.

Comment: @xzczd, it works for me without setting that in v11.0 and v11.2

Comment: Oh, did you test with the modified equation system i.e. the one with a second `Clip`? I tested with the original one.

Comment: @xzczd, thanks a lot for the bounty! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The `10^-10` in `Clip` is indeed causing trouble, but not in `Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)]`, because the `mconly` warning still pops up even after the technique mentioned in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25668/1871) is used.

So, what's the root of the problem? I'm not sure, nevertheless, the problem can be resolved by changing `10^-10` to something a bit larger:

```
eq = {Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau], 
   Q[tau] == 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6, 
   tr[tau] == tt[tau] + (28 - tt[tau]) (10^-10 + Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)]), 
   vF[tau] - Clip[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])), {0.1(*See here!*), 100}] == 0, 
   tt[1] == 15, tr[1] == 15, 
   vF[1] == 100, Q[1] == 0};
sol0 = NDSolveValue[eq, tt, {tau, 0, 24}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

 {sol0, sol2}[24] // Through
 (* {20.2045, 20.2045} *)
```

The result at `tau == 24` is the same as that of `sol2`, so I think this solution is acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've also considered your suggestion. However, the error is  bigger than my acceptable value. Is there any way to keep the `10^-10` and still get it working?

Comment: @407Peezy Sadly I don't know. Actually similar problems have appeared in this site for many times and I never see them being solved in a direct way i.e. by adjusting options, as you've mentioned. I myself tend to take it as the current limitation of DAE solver in _Mathematica_. I sincerely hope I'm wrong.

Comment: That would be really quite a pity if Mathematica DAE solve is not able to process this kind of equation.

Answer (score 7):

The block of code in the question following "However, if I eliminate some equations with Rule, it runs smoothly" works, because the transformation changes the differential-algebraic system to a purely differential system, for which `NDSolve` uses more robust solution methods.  The same can be accomplished more generally by expressing the variables appearing only algebraically as functions of `tt`.  Here, the functions are

```
Qf[tt_?NumericQ] := 100 (28 - trf[tt]) vFf[tt] 7/6;
trf[tt_?NumericQ] := tt + (28 - tt) Exp[-(270/77)/vFf[tt]];
vFf[tt_?NumericQ] := Clip[(20 + 20 (20 - tt)), {10^-10, 100}];
```

and the system, now a single ODE, is solved by

```
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
eq = {Qf[tt[tau]] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau], tt[1] == 15};
sol1 = Flatten[NDSolveValue[eq, {tt}, {tau, 0, 24}]];
ul = sol1[[1]]["Domain"][[1, 2]];
Plot[sol1[[1]][tau], {tau, 0, ul}, AxesLabel -> {tau, tt}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

In general, the variables appearing only algebraically can be converted into functions, although some care must be taken, if they are not single-valued.

As an aside, the original system of equations in the question, when rewritten as

```
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
eq = {Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau],
      vF[tau] == Clip[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])), {3 10^-3, 100}] , 
      tr[tau] == tt[tau] + (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)],
      Q[tau] == 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6,
      tt[1] == 15, tr[1] == 15, vF[1] == 100, Q[1] == 0};
sol0 = Flatten[NDSolveValue[eq, {tt, tr, vF, Q}, {tau, 0, 24}]];
```

also runs to completion, because the lower limit of `Clip` now is set to `3 10^-3`, which I would think would be good enough for most purposes.  (The exponential in the question can assume a minimum value as small as about `10^-305`.)  Incidentally, the warning messages, `NDSolveValue::ivres` returned by this latter block of code indicate that the `NDSolve` has corrected the initial conditions for consistency:

```
Table[sol0[[i]][1], {i, 4}]
(* {15., 27.5521, 100., 5226.02} *)
```

Using these values instead of those in the question eliminates the warning messages.

**Addendum: Result for imported `li`**

The first block of code in this answer also can handle the imported version of `li`, despite the fact that the resulting `tae` is very noisy.

```
li = Import["http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/725958TYA.CSV"];
tae = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[8760], Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}]];
Plot[tae[tau], {tau, 1, 24 365}, AxesLabel -> {tau, "tae"}, PlotRange -> All, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Then, the first block of code, integrated over `{tau, 1, 24 365}`, yields

[image]

Incidentally, the second block of code with the lower bound of `Clip` set to `5 10^-2` reproduces the final plot above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, like already mentioned, the real problem cannot be easily rewritten into pure ODE system. Thus, it would be better, if it doesn't require to transform the DAE system into ODE system.

Comment: And the to 2nd part. Although it runs to the end with `3 10^-3` in the simplified version, it still fails to run to completion for the full interpolated function `tae[tau]`. `mconly` still appears.

Comment: However, I have to admit, it seems that the ODE solver is really more stable than the DAE solver.

Comment: @407Peezy  Don't be too quick to dismiss using functions to eliminate algebraic equations.  How many differential equations and how many algebraic equations are included in your complete problem?

Comment: There are 12 differential equations and 12 algebraic ones

Comment: @407Peezy  Twelve seems like a manageable number, especially if the algebraic variables are single-valued functions of the other variables.  If not, then care will be needed to follow the correct branches of the algebraic variables, especially if they cross.  But, that could be true in the original differential-algebraic system too.

Comment: @407Peezy  With respect to your second comment here, running the second block of code in my answer on the complete `tae` does not give me an `NDSolveValue:: mconly` error.  Instead , it gives me an `NDSolveValue::ndsz` error, indicating stiffness.  The IDA algorithm as implemented in Mathematica does not appear to have am option for dealing with this problem.  Instead, all three answers that stay with your original DAE system increase the lower bound of `Clip` to circumvent it.  The question is, can you live with a lower bound of, say, `5 10^-2`?

Comment: It appears that I have to accept `5 10^-2`, although the accuracy in the real problem might be not very satisfying. It's really pity to see that NDSolve has difficulty to deal with some DAEs (especially in my case).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share some new findings to this post after nearly 2 years.

As described in the question, running the original code gives me the `NDSolve::mconly` error.

```
li = Import["http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/725958TYA.CSV"];
tae = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[8760], Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}]]
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
eq0 = {Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau],
       Q[tau] - 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 == 0,
       tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 (vF[tau]) 0.22)] == 0,
       vF[tau] - Clip[20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau]), {$MachineEpsilon, 100}] == 0}
ic0 = FindRoot[eq0[[All, 1]] == 0 /. tau -> 1, 
               Transpose[{{Q[1], tt[1], tr[1], vF[1]}, {3000, 20, 20, 20}}], 
               MaxIterations -> 10000] /. Rule -> Equal

sol0 = Monitor[NDSolve[Rationalize[Join[eq0, ic0]], {Q, tt, tr, vF}, 
                       {tau, 1, 24 365}, 
                       EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", tau}])], 
               monitor][[1]]
(* NDSolve::mconly error *)
```

But if I modify the third equation `tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 (vF[tau]) 0.22)] == 0` into `tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 Max[$MachineEpsilon, vF[tau]] 0.22)] == 0`, NDSolve returns a different error message `NDSolve::ndsz`. This is quite interesting. My guess is that NDSolve thought it might be a good idea to try `vF[tau] == 0` in the equation at some step which might result in `NDSolve::mconly` error for IDA solver.

The next thing I tried is to eliminate the second equation `Q[tau] - 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 == 0` and surprisingly it works.

```
eq2 = {100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau],
       tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 Max[vF[tau], $MachineEpsilon] 0.22)] == 0,
       vF[tau] - Clip[20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau]), {$MachineEpsilon, 100}] == 0}
ic2 = FindRoot[eq2[[All, 1]] == 0 /. tau -> 1, 
               Transpose[{{tt[1], tr[1], vF[1]}, {20, 20, 20}}], 
               MaxIterations -> 10000] /. Rule -> Equal
AbsoluteTiming[sol2 = Monitor[NDSolve[Rationalize[Join[eq2, ic2]], {tt, tr, vF}, {tau, 1, 24 365}, EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", tau}])], monitor][[1]];]
(* 64.5397 *)
```

This leads me to take a deeper look into the second equation. Actually for the equation solving, the second equation is not necessary. We can solve the `tt` and calculate the `Q` afterwards. After some brief investigation, it turns out that the second equation is quite stiff. If we insert the forth equation and the third equation in to the second, we will have a function $Q(tt(\tau))$. If we plot the function $Q(tt(\tau))$, we can easily see where the problem is.

```
rl1 = {Q[tau] -> 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6, 
       tr[tau] -> tt[tau] + (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 Max[$MachineEpsilon, vF[tau]] 0.22)],
       vF[tau] -> Clip[20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau]), {$MachineEpsilon, 100}]}
Plot[(rl1[[1, 2]] //. Drop[rl1, 1]) /. {tt[tau] -> x}, {x, 15, 25}, AxesLabel -> {"tt", "Q"}]
```

[image: Plot]

The curve becomes very steep when the $tt$ increases to 21 and after 21 the curve becomes flat. If we extract the values for the last steps in `sol0`, we will see that the last values for $tt$ is around 21.

After all these back and forth and trying for really couple years, I come to a conclusion concerning using `NDSolve`, which I want to tell myself repeatedly and share with everyone:

**Always check the equation first before using `NDSolve`, even they have physical meaning.**

Comment: Er… then why do you include the second equation at the beginning?

Comment: @xzczd Because this variable is something I would like to have at first.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that setting the `WorkingPrecision` to 8 simply solves this problem.

```
li = Import["http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/725958TYA.CSV"];
tae = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[8760], Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}]]

Cwirk = 50 25 3;
eq = {Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau],
      Q[tau] - 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 == 0, 
      tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)] == 0,
      vF[tau] - Clip[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])), {10^(-10), 100}] == 0}
ic = FindRoot[eq[[All, 1]] == 0 /. tau -> 1, Transpose[{{Q[1], tt[1], tr[1], vF[1]}, {3000, 20, 20, 20}}]] /. Rule -> Equal

workingPrecision = 8;
AbsoluteTiming[
 sol = NDSolve[SetPrecision[Join[eq, ic], workingPrecision], {Q, tt, tr, vF}, {tau, 1, 24 365}, WorkingPrecision -> workingPrecision, MaxSteps -> Infinity];]
(* {31.2564, Null} *)
```

But somehow the `Rule` method doesn't work anymore on my MMA 12.0 mac.

```
rs = {Q -> 100 (28 - tr) vF 7/6, 
   tr -> tt[tau] + (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF 0.22)], 
   vF -> Clip[20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau]), {10^(-10), 100}]};
eq2 = Q - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == tt'[tau];
AbsoluteTiming[
 sol2 = Flatten[
   NDSolveValue[{eq2 //. rs, tt[1] == 18.887256814210946}, 
    tt, {tau, 1, 24 365}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]]]

NDSolveValue::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at tau == 3497.9989465540943`; unable to continue
```

**EDIT**

Here is another solution for this case. I always thought that NDSolve does not particularly like discontinuous functions such as `Clip`, `Min`, `Max`. It is possible to replace them with some events. Below a discrete variable `mode` is used to indicate if the function is below zero or above 100. If below zero, then the `mode` will be set to -1. If above 100, it will be set to 1. Otherwise, it is 0. Using the `mode` variable, `Clip` can be avoided.

```
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
li = Import["http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/725958TYA.CSV"];
tae = 
 Interpolation[
  Transpose[{Range[8760], Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}]]

eq1 = {
  Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - tae[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau],  
  Q[tau] - 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 == 0,
  tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/7/6 vF[tau] 0.22] == 0,
  vF[tau] - DiscreteDelta[mode[tau] - 1] 100 - 
    DiscreteDelta[mode[tau]] (20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])) - 
    DiscreteDelta[mode[tau] + 1] $MachineEpsilon == 0}
ic1 = Join[
   FindRoot[eq1[[All, 1]] == 0 /. {tau -> 1, mode[_] -> 0}, 
    Transpose[{{Q[1], tt[1], tr[1], vF[1]}, {3000, 20, 20, 
       20}}]], {mode[1] -> 0}] /. Rule -> Equal
evts1 = {WhenEvent[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])) < $MachineEpsilon, 
   mode[tau] -> -1], 
  WhenEvent[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])) > 100, mode[tau] -> 1], 
  WhenEvent[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])) < 100, mode[tau] -> 0], 
  WhenEvent[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])) > $MachineEpsilon, 
   mode[tau] -> 0]}
AbsoluteTiming[
 sol1 = NDSolve[
     Join[eq1, evts1, ic1], {Q, tt, tr, vF, mode}, {tau, 1, 24 365}, 
     DiscreteVariables -> mode][[1]];]
(* {73.7385, Null} *)
```

It's worth mentioning that this method is 2x slower than simply setting `WorkingPrecision` to 8.

Comment: Seems that `"StateSpace"` method is triggered by `WorkingPrecision` option. (``{state}=NDSolve`ProcessEquations[…]; state["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"]`` shows that `NDSolve` is still dealing with a DAE system,  `StateSpace` seems to be the only available DAE solver for arbitrary precision in this case, and adding `Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"StateSpace"}}` to your code doesn't seem to change the timing. ) It's a bit surprising that adding `WorkingPrecision->8` speeds up the code.

Comment: Another somewhat surprising thing is, adding `SolveDelayed->True` to the sample fails in _v12_ resolves the problem.

Comment: @xzczd I guess that the speeding up with `WorkingPrecision->8` is probably because the default `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` is half of the `WorkingPrecision` according to the `NDSolve` documentation.