# Mathematica NDSolve for DAE and System Modeling

Tags: differential-equations, system-modeler, system-modeling

I'm a student for HVAC engineering and I've been using Mathematica for my study (mostly differential-algebraic equation system or Finite-Element-Analysis) and my hobby project for years. I really enjoy Mathematica, but I always have been struggling with `NDSolve` and its DAE solver, because it seems to be not very robust (see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167368/ndsolve-dae-with-constraints)).

I have this feeling that `NDSolve` (or `IDA`) does not particularly favor discontinuous functions such as `Clip`, `Min`, `Max`. For most engineering problems and modeling method, I think that these functions are not avoidable. I've been browsing this forum for solutions quite a long time and there appeared some solutions for it, but they are mostly only for some specific case and not applicable for my case (e.g. a simple P-controller with a minimum of a close-to-zero value such as `$MachineEpsilon` will very likely trigger the `NDSolve::ndsz` error for unknown reasons, not sure if it's a bug or not).

Till recent, I found that since v11 Mathematica allows connection to Modelica with `CreateSystemModel`. I've heard that Modelica has a strong DAE solver and I would really like to test this Mathematica-Modelica feature. But the documentation for System Modeling seems to be not very detailed. For the first trial I would like to realize a simple house heating model from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167368/ndsolve-dae-with-constraints).

```
(* effective heat capacity of building *)
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
(* import outdoor temperature *)
li = Import[
   "http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/\
725958TYA.CSV"];
(* interpolate outdoor temperature *)
tae = Transpose[{Range[8760], Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}]
eq = {
  (* equation for building *)
  Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - ta[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau], 
  (* heating capacity of floor heating system *)
  Q[tau] - 100 (28 - tr[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6 == 0, 
  (* the water outlet temperature of floor heating *)
  tr[tau] - tt[tau] - (28 - tt[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 vF[tau] 0.22)] == 0,
  (* a simple P-controller for the flow rate *) 
  vF[tau] - Max[Min[(20 + 20 (20 - tt[tau])), 100], 10^(-10)] == 0}
```

Here is what I've got so far.

```
model = CreateSystemModel[eq, tau]
data = CreateDataSystemModel[tae]
wholeModel = 
 ConnectSystemModelComponents[{model, data}, {"ta" \[Element] data}]
```

The connection seems to be unsuccessful and `SystemModelSimulate` returns nothing. It would be really appreciated if a simple example can be provided for the new System Model feature.

**EDIT**

Here is a simplified version of the above problem. It is about the thermal behavior of a house. The thermal resistance is `R` (e.g. $1/200 \frac{K}{W}$) and it has a heat capacity of `Cwirk` (e.g. $50 \cdot 25 \cdot 3 \frac{W h}{K}$). The variable `t` is the room temperature and `ta` is the outdoor ambient temperature. `Q` stands for the heating output of the in-house heating device (we can set `Q` to a constant such as $1000 W$). So the conservation equation is

$$ C_{Wirk} \cdot \frac{dt}{d\tau} = - \frac{t - t_a}{R} + \dot{Q} $$

The `t_a` is obviously an input to this model. We can use the weather data from the list `tae`.

```
li = Import[
   "http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/\
725958TYA.CSV"];
(* interpolate outdoor temperature *)
tae = Transpose[{Range[8760], Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}]
```

It's unclear for me how to connect the weather data to the equation/model. It would be very appreciated if any explanation or maybe an example can be provided.

Comment: The question is very interesting. However, the variables (such as `vF`, `tt`, `li`, `tae`) and the equations are very misleading to me. If you are new to Mathematica's system model, I suggest to use a simple enough system.

Comment: ConnectSystemModelComponents works with components that have connectors. You probably need to specify in CreateSystemModel which variables are connectors, and then use those connectors to connect it with the data model. I suggest reading the documentation page of [ConnectSystemModelComponents](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectSystemModelComponents.html).

Comment: @xinxinguo I've added a simplified example.

Comment: @MalteLenz thank you for the link. Actually, this is exactly what I'm confused about. After reading this documentation, I still have no idea how to connect an external list to the defined model.

Comment: Maybe [this example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html#2095119923) is useful.

Comment: @user21 thank you for the example. The code in the example seems to trigger Mathematica FEM. Can FEM solver also handle the differential-algebraic system?

Comment: @407PZ, FEM is a spatial discretization, the time integration is then done with IDA which seems to work just fine in this case.

Comment: @user21 the `IDA` fails for the equations in the first code block in this post (these equations come originally from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167368/ndsolve-dae-with-constraints)), when a very small value involved inside the `Max` to avoid 1/0 error. I've been really struggling with this problem for quite a long time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your simplified version, and using hard-coded data, create the model with the data source:

```
data = {{0, 6}, {1, 9}, {2, 1}, {3, 9}, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, {6, 1}, {7, 
    8}, {8, 0}, {9, 2}, {10, 9}};
datamodel = CreateDataSystemModel[data]
```

Define your parameters:

```
cwirk = 50 25 3;
q = 1000;
r = 1/200;
```

Create the model containing the equations. Note that we are defining the `ta` as a Real input:

```
eqmodel = 
 CreateSystemModel[{cwirk t'[tau] == (t[tau] - ta[tau])/r + q}, 
  tau, {ta \[Element] "RealInput"}]
```

Connect them. Note how we connect the output from the data model, `data.y[1]`, to the input we created in the equation model, `eqs.ta`:

```
simmodel = ConnectSystemModelComponents[
   {"data" \[Element] datamodel, "eqs" \[Element] eqmodel},
   {"data.y[1]" -> "eqs.ta"}
]
```

And then you can simulate and plot:

```
sim = SystemModelSimulate[simmodel, 10]
SystemModelPlot[sim, {"eqs.t"}]
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I need!

Comment: I tried your code in Mathematica. It returns `Notification: The initialization problem is underdetermined, the \
following variables where chosen to be initialized from their start \
values: eqs.t.` error and `Error: Compilation of generated code failed (exit code 1). Build log:
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.\
xctoolc\[Ellipsis] ~~~
 17 errors generated.
 *** Error code 1
 
 Stop in /private/var/folders/8b/yyk12r657g3cmld0fs36r_4m0000gn/T/\
WolframSystemModeler-12.0.` Does it mean that I have to install SystemModeler?

Comment: You don't need SystemModeler, but you need to install a C++ compiler. In the case of macOS, you should be able to follow this guide: https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/compiler-mac/
If you are using Catalina and some versions of XCode you may need to apply a workaround: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/48717
Since you don't have SystemModeler you will need to set the "PlatformSDKPath" using the tools from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WSMLink/tutorial/CompilerForSystemModeler.html instead.

Comment: I got it working! I have Xcode but I had to manually set the PlatformSDKPath with `SystemModelConfiguration`SetConfiguration[]`. Thank you!