# NDSolve big system non linear coupled ODE's Method Residual Stiff System

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I'm trying to develop a continuous time unscented Kalman filter for a dynamic system inspired to this article: "On Unscented Kalman Filtering for State Estimation of Continuous-Time Nonlinear Systems" of the author Simo Särkkä. In particular the Square Root one.

My systems has dimension 5 so I have a system of 11 x 5 + 15 non linear coupled first order differential equations.

The code of my notebook is very long and laborious, in the end I simulate a dynamic system and the filter receive the output.

When I try to solve the system with NDSolve it says:


[image]

So I do as recommended and it works till it find a singularity that I think is just numerical and not due to the system.

Maybe using Chop to simplify the approximations as I saw in other posts.


This is a short versione of my code:

```
t0 = 0;
tfin = 4 Pi;
pstl = {xstl, ystl};
R0l[\[Theta]_] = {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]} , {Sin[\[Theta]], 
    Cos[\[Theta]]}};
pmk1 = {xmk1, ymk1};
pmk2 = {xmk2, ymk2};
numericalvalues = 
  Thread[{l1, l2, xstl, ystl, xmk1, ymk1, xmk2, ymk2} -> {8, 5, 
     3, -2, 32, 16, -15, 2}];


qalist = {x, y, \[Theta], xstls, ystls};
qa[t_] = (ToString[#] <> "[t]") & /@ qalist // ToExpression;
qad[t_] = D[qa[t], t];
qadd[t_] = D[qa[t], t];

v[t_] = 2;
\[Omega][t_] = 1;
input[t_] = {v[t], \[Omega][t]};



g1 = {Cos[#], Sin[#], 0, 0, 0} & @(#[[3]]) &;
g2 = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
dyn = (g1@#*v[t] + g2*\[Omega][t]) &;


pstf = ({#1, #2} + R0l[#3 ].{#4, #5}) &;
h1 = (Sqrt[#.#] &[pmk1 - pstf @@ #]) &;
h2 = (Sqrt[#.#] &[pmk2 - pstf @@ # ]) &;



CreateWhiteNoise[\[Mu]_, s_, t0_, tfin_, dt_, p_] := 
 Module[{distr, n = Length[\[Mu]], listt, nc, listrn},
    listt = Range[t0, tfin, dt];
    nc = Length[listt];
    distr = MultinormalDistribution[\[Mu], s];
    listrn = RandomVariate[distr, nc];
    (Interpolation[Thread[Join[{listt, listrn[[All, #]]}]]][p]) & /@ 
   Range@n
  ] (*Just create white noise continuous time sample*)


cov = {{0.008, 0}, {0, 
   0.008}}; (*(0.008//Sqrt) *3 \[Equal] 0.268 [m]*)
media = {0, 0};
noise = CreateWhiteNoise[media, cov, t0, tfin + 0.1, 0.04, t ];


h = {h1@#, h2@#} & ;
hn = (h@# + noise) &;
output[t_] = Join[h@qa[t], hn@qa[t]] /. numericalvalues;


eqdyn = qad[t] == dyn@qa[t];

qa0 = Flatten@{-2, 1, Pi/3, pstl} /. numericalvalues;
eqin = qa[0] == qa0;

monitor = {qa[t], input[t], output[t]};

{state, in, out} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqdyn, eqin}, monitor, {t, t0, tfin}];

ParametricPlot[state[[1 ;; 2]], {t, t0, tfin}]
```

And I get the desired result:

[image]

If now I want to use the filter as in the paper:

```
qlisthat = (ToString@# <> "hat" // ToExpression) & /@ qalist ;
qahat[t_] = (ToString@# <> "[t]" // ToExpression) & /@ qlisthat;
qahatd[t_] = D[qahat[t], t];
nstate = Length@qlisthat;

Covariance Matrix

Pmat = Array[ToExpression[("P" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2])] &, 
   IdentityMatrix[nstate] // Dimensions];
P[t_] = Array[ToExpression[(ToString@Pmat[[#1, #2]] <> "[t]")] &, 
   Dimensions[Pmat]];
Pd[t_] = D[P[t], t];

Initial estimate

P0 = IdentityMatrix[nstate]*{0.005, 0.005, 0.3 Degree, 0.005, 
    0.005 };
stima0 = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[ qa0, P0]];
initstima = qahat[0] == stima0;
initcov = P[0] == P0;
initEKF = {initstima, initcov};

FILTER PARAMETERS AND VARIABLES

k = 1;
\[Alpha] = 1;
\[Beta] = 0;
nsp = 2 nstate + 1;
\[Lambda] = \[Alpha]^2 (nstate + k) - nstate;
c = Sqrt[\[Alpha]^2 (nstate + k)];

Covariance matrix factorization

decP = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i >= j :> 
     ToExpression["a" <> ToString[(10 #1 + #2) &[i, j]]] , 
    Dimensions[Pmat]] // Normal;
Dec[t_] = 
  Array[If[decP[[#1, #2]] == 0, 0 , 
     0, (ToString@decP[[#1, #2]] <> "[t]" ) // ToExpression] &, 
   Dimensions@Pmat];
Decd[t_] = D[Dec[t], t];

Sigma Points

XSP =  SparseArray[{{i_, 
        j_} :> ("xsp"  <> ToString@i <> ToString@j )} , {nsp, 
      nstate}] // Normal // Transpose;
X[t_] = Array[(ToString@XSP[[#1, #2]] <> "[t]" // ToExpression) &, 
   Dimensions@XSP];
Xd[t_] = D[X[t], t];

Sigma points propagation

propX = dyn /@ (X[t]\[Transpose]) // Transpose // Simplify;

Sigma points output

Ysp = {h1 /@ (X[t]\[Transpose]), h2 /@ (X[t]\[Transpose])} /. 
    numericalvalues // Simplify;
z = Transpose@D[hn /@ (X[t]\[Transpose]), t] /. numericalvalues;

Weights

w0 = \[Lambda] / (nstate + \[Lambda]);
w = 1 / ( 2 (nstate + \[Lambda]));
w0' = w0 + 1 - \[Alpha]^2 + \[Beta];
wm = Append[{w0}, Table[w, nsp - 1]] // Flatten;
Wm = Table[wm, nsp] // Transpose;
wc = ReplacePart[wm, 1 -> w0'];
Wc = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> w0', {i_, i_} /; i > 1 -> w}, 
    nsp {1, 1}] // Normal;
W = (IdentityMatrix[nsp] - Wm).Wc.Transpose[
     IdentityMatrix[nsp] - Wm] // Simplify;

FILTER EQUATIONS

\[CapitalPhi][mat_] := 
  Module[{i, j}, 
   SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> mat[[i, i]]/2, {i_, j_} /; i > j :> 
       mat[[i, j]] }, Dimensions[mat]] // Normal];
StackCols[l__?MatrixQ] := MapThread[Join, {l}];
ZeroMatrix[m_, n_] := Normal@SparseArray[{}, {m, n}];
ListForm[mat_] := 
 DeleteCases[(Thread@# & /@ Thread@mat // Flatten ), True]


K = X[t].W. Ysp\[Transpose].Inverse[cov];
U = propX.W.X[t]\[Transpose] + X[t].W.propX\[Transpose] - 
   K.cov.K\[Transpose];
M = Inverse@Dec[t].U.Transpose[Inverse@Dec[t]];
stimaSRUKBF = X[t].wm;
eqDecP = Decd[t] == Dec[t].\[CapitalPhi][M];
eqX = Xd[t] == 
   propX.Wm + K.(z - Ysp.Wm) + 
    c * StackCols[ZeroMatrix[nstate, 1], 
      Dec[t].\[CapitalPhi][M], -Dec[t].\[CapitalPhi][M]];
eqSRUKBF = {ListForm@eqDecP, eqX};

INITIAL CONDITIONS

A0 = CholeskyDecomposition@P0;
X0 = Transpose[Table[stima0, nsp]] + 
   c * StackCols[ZeroMatrix[nstate, 1], A0, -A0];
initDecp = Dec[0] == A0;
initX = X[0] == X0;
initSRUKBF = {ListForm@initDecp, initX};

INTEGRATION
errstima = qa[t] - stimaSRUKBF;
monitorSRUKBF = {qa[t], stimaSRUKBF, errstima, Xd[t]\[Transpose]};
(*Xd[t] are the derivatives cause singularity*)

(*With[{opts=SystemOptions[]},Internal`WithLocalSettings[\
SetSystemOptions["NDSolveOptions"\[Rule]"DefaultSolveTimeConstraint"\
\[Rule]10.],{stat, statoSRUKBF, errstimaSRUKBF} = NDSolveValue[{eqns, \
eqin, eqSRUKBF, initSRUKBF}, monitorSRUKBF, 
{t,t0,0.04}];,SetSystemOptions[opts]]]*)

(*{stat, statoSRUKBF, errstimaSRUKBF} = NDSolveValue[{eqdyn, eqin, \
eqSRUKBF, initSRUKBF}, monitorSRUKBF, 
{t,t0,0.04}];*)

{stat, statoSRUKBF, errstimaSRUKBF, der} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqdyn, eqin, eqSRUKBF, initSRUKBF}, monitorSRUKBF, 
   {t, t0, 0.5}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"} ];

(*NDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 0.1982530364128179`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.*)

Plot[der, {t, t0, 0.25}]
```

[image]

The plot shows the derivatives of the variables that cause singularity.
I don't know if is there a way to make the equations in a simpler form that NDSolve can handle, or if is there some trick I can use to manage singularities. The fact is that I think singularity is a numerical matter and not due to the formal system.
\

**EDIT**
Replace just these lines of code to make things work:

```
z = D[hn@qa[t], t] /. numericalvalues // Simplify;
Z = Table[z, nsp] // Transpose;

eqX = Xd[t] == 
  propX.Wm + K.(Z - Ysp.Wm) + 
   c * StackCols[ZeroMatrix[nstate, 1], 
     Dec[t].\[CapitalPhi][M], -Dec[t].\[CapitalPhi][M]]
```

And now the system doesn't go on singularity. Before happened because the Dec[t] lost rank during system evolution, but it shouldn't happen, so I've found out the filter's equations weren't right obtaining the following results instead of the previous ones
[image]

Comment: please provide your code your attempted so we can test ourselves.

Comment: Apparently related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131411/why-does-ndsolve-need-to-solve-for-the-derivatives-if-the-equations-are-already/

Comment: @morbo thanks for your advice I've followed it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I had already seen that post, I've anyway posted the the output of NDSolve in the case I do as recommended. Thanks the same

Comment: I get a bunch of errors that seem significant. before `NDSolve` is called. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: I don't think `NDSolve` can handle arbitrary delays (e.g. `Derivative[1][R0l][xsp103[t]]`), but maybe the prior errors resulted in an incorrect system.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You got reason, I omitted one part of the code in the attempt of simplifying the original one, my mistake. I've updated the code with the corrections but is the same story

Comment: `initSRUKBF` involves a number of `0==0`, please double check it.

Comment: @xzczd I've followed you and I have updated the code using a function called ListForm to handle it. Now it says to use EquationSimplification -> Residual, and if I do it there is a strange error I'm gonna post. Thanks for the advice i feel is a step toward the solution

Comment: `n` in `w = 1 / ( 2 (n + \[Lambda]));` is not defined.

Comment: @xzczd God bless you ! I've modified the code. Now it finally works ! Till 0.25 when there is a singularity, do you know if is there a way to avoid it ? (I modify the post now). I've also noticed that NDSolve treats zeroes as 1*10^(-30) for example when I went inside the previous error messages. Do you know if Chop could be useful to simplify the problem ?

Comment: First of all, I'd suggest double-checking the system to make sure the system itself is indeed correct. If so, then things become troublesome. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167368/1871

Comment: @xzczd You got reason another time. There is a mistake in the filters equations, I've fixed it and now it works without going on singularity even if the filter behavior is not very good but I don't think this is a numerical issue

Comment: @PeaceEverybody: If you achieved to have the running code, could you please post it.

Comment: @PeaceEverybody yes, please post your updated running code. Definitely curious what you've got working, you could even post it as an answer to your own question (with a nice shout out to xzczd ;) )

Comment: @morbo, Tugrul Turnel  I've shown my solution under EDIT. I know it's not a general solution to the question but maybe can be usefull to show a thinking line that could be useful