# Why does 1 - Exp[-10.0^12] cause an out-of-memory error?

Tags: numerics, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I would like to understand why evaluation of the expression

```
1 - Exp[-10.0^12]
```

causes an out-of-memory error and how can I prevent such errors when calculating numeric integrals with decaying exponents.

For example an attempt to evaluate the following numeric integral:

```
f[x_Real, y_Real] := (1 - Exp[-x^2]) E^(-x Sqrt[1 + 1/2 (1 - y^2)]);
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

causes the following error message on Windows:

> `Throw::sysexc`: Uncaught `SystemException` returned to top level. Can be caught with `Catch[…, _SystemException]`. >>
>
> ```
> SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
> ```

while on OSX it causes a kernel restart.

**Update:** From the discussion in comments it became clear that when Mathematica encounters an exponent of a very large negative number (i.e. when the result cannot be represented as machine precision number) it automatically converts the number to arbitrary precision 
(see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/)).
One can prevent this conversion from happening using the command:

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False];
```

This trick makes evaluation of the above expressions possible.

What is still interesting to understand is why the evaluation of difference of arbitrary precision numbers causes a memory error.

Comment: ["Machine numbers have not only limited precision, but also limited magnitude. If you generate a number that lies outside the range specified by `$MinMachineNumber` and `$MaxMachineNumber`, the Wolfram Language will automatically convert the number to arbitrary‐precision form."](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html#26994)

Comment: Why did you remove your previous question? For me, this fact alone cannot fully explain what was happening.

Comment: With your numerical definition, `NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]` runs without problem. It seems that the problem depends on methods specified.

Comment: It uses under 200K of memory on my machine.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Could you, please, check with a higher power of ten? I.e. `1 - Exp[-10.0^12]`

Comment: @Shadowray I'm sure it eventually will run out.  Unless I get `Underflow[]` (around 10^-16). :)  I just wondered, since I imagine you have at least a few GBs.

Comment: @MichaelE2 it looks like this behavior depends on the operating system. In my case OSX 10.12.3 silently kills the kernel after it consumes 65GB of virtual RAM. I get no `Underflow[]` (or any other) warnings from *Mathematica*, just a beep and restart of the kernel.

Comment: Taking it from the top: Here is a smaller example where we exponentiate a machine real and get something else. `In[405]:= InputForm[e3 = Exp[-10.0^3]]
Out[405]//InputForm=
5.07595889754945676529180948`12.954589770191006*^-435` So e3 is an arbitrary precision number because it cannot be represented by a machine number. Now what should one expect from the computation `1-e3`? It cannot be an exact number and it cannot be a machine number. The subtraction will produce .99...until the significant digits of `e3` are encountered. Not much else it can do (unless there is a memory exception).

Comment: Thank you @DanielLichtblau! I understood your arguments and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually this is not a duplicate. The prior question is about underflows that require massive bignums to represent at machine precision, and that much is present here as well. So what @J.M notes is certainly a part of the issue. But it is not entirely a matter of cancellation error and a need to represent a very small number.

The problem is a combination of the below.

(1) A bignum is required for representing `Exp[-10.0^4]` even at $MachinePrecision digits.

(2) That number has low precision but high accuracy.

(3) The subtraction now involves a bignum of high accuracy and an exact number.

Were it a machine `1.0` it would be a different matter, and coercion would kick in and deliver a machine `1.0`. But we have an exact and a bignum, of high accuracy, so the subtraction delivers a high accuracy result that requires the many digits.

Comment: Is it a bug? A workaround seems to set `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]`. Does this setting has undesirable side-effects?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's how significance arithmetic works. What the `SystemOption` does is to disable the transformation of what would be a machine underflow into a bignum, which in turn allows the arithmetic to remain in the realm of machine numbers.

Comment: Thank you, got it. Another example of this behavior is `1 - SetAccuracy[0, 10^12]`.